# Cannot unmarshal JSON-to-object with JAX-RS (CXF)

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cxf

Using latest version of CXF and other dependencies, I'm trying to unit test web services which produces and consumes JSON. Test works when method argument is String, but fails when argument is custom object. Following is the sample resource:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("testPost")
public Employee getPostTest(Employee data) {
    return data;
}
```

Following is the excerpt of a test case

```
    List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<Object>();
    providers.add(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider());
    WebClient client = WebClient.create(ENDPOINT_ADDRESS, providers);
    client.accept("application/json");
    client.type("application/json");
    client.path("users/testPost/");
    Employee e = new Employee();
    e.setName("Test");
    Response r = client.post(e);
```

Last line of the above code throws the following exception:

> Dec 05, 2016 2:46:50 AM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils logMessageHandlerProblem
>   SEVERE: No message body reader has been found for class com.finity.model.Employee, ContentType: application/json
>   Dec 05, 2016 2:46:50 AM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
>   WARNING: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1315)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:826)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:789)

Tried the read using JSONParser but no go:

```
    Employee e = new Employee();
    e.setName("Test");
    Response r = client.post(e);

    MappingJsonFactory factory = new MappingJsonFactory();
    JsonParser parser = factory.createJsonParser((InputStream)r.getEntity());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the JSON provider. For example Jackson

```
 <jaxrs:providers>
   <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
  </jaxrs:providers>
```

or `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` (when working with JAXB beans)

It is needed also to add the maven dependency if you do not have it. 
    
      org.codehaus.jackson
      jackson-jaxrs
      1.9.0

See CXF [JSON support](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html#JAX-RSDataBindings-JSONsupport)

Comment: Yes that is already added but still that exception is coming. providers.add(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider()); and providers.add(new JacksonJsonProvider()); tried both these providers.

Comment: Are you using Jaxb? Please, post the code of `Employee` to see which tags are you using, and the code which is launching the jax-rs server

Comment: Employee model is a POJO class with only name field and no annotation on class. Though I tried JsonAutoDetect and JsonSerialize annotations on Employee class but that didn't help.

Comment: The simplest way to work with CXF and JSON is using JAXB. Please, add `@XmlRootElement(name = "Employee")` and add `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` to your jax-rs server

Comment: Tried but its still showing the same error. providers.add(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider()); and added XmlRootElement on top of Employee class

Comment: any other thoughts...CXF is not able to find message body reader for any custom object. Initially it wasn't able to find message body writer but adding JacksonJaxbJsonProvider resolved that...need a way to add a reader

Comment: One moment, the exception is raised on client side or on server side?

Comment: its a junit test case, exception occurs on WebClient.create(ENDPOINT_ADDRESS, providers).post(obj)

Comment: Are you sure the server is returning a Json response? Seems the  exception is raised on server, not on client side. My answer indicates how to configure the server. On client side, your code seems ok

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this solution will work for everyone or not but this is how I solved it.

My `Employee` class was initially like this:

```
@Data
public class Employee {
    private String attribute1;
    private String attribute2;
}
```

@Data is a Lombok annotation that provides the Getters, Setters, and toString method to the class.

I updated MyRequest class with these annotations:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    private String attribute1;
    private String attribute2;
}
```

That is I have added these 3 following new annotations to my class and it solved the issue.
@NoArgsConstructor 
@AllArgsConstructor 
@XmlRootElement

@NoArgsConstructor is a Lombok annotation that creates a no-argument constructor.

@AllArgsConstructor is a Lombok annotation that creates an all-argument constructor.

@XmlRootElement is from javax.xml.bind package and it causes a global element declaration to be produced in the schema. The global element declaration is associated with the XML schema type to which the class is mapped.

Although I didn't get the time to seclude each of the 3 annotations one by one to see which one actually fixed this issue but my hunch is adding the `@XmlRootElement` annotation might have fixed this issue for me.